# How to grab specific <p> when multiple at same level?

Tags: jquery

I have an html structure like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <h4>Available since...</h4>
    <div class="markdown">
        <p>Version 1</p>
    </div>
    <h4>Accessible by...</h4>
    <div class="markdown">
        <p>SOME TEXT I NEED TO ANALYZE</p>
    </div>
    <h4>Description</h4>
    <div class="markdown">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the text in the second p-tag (SOME TEXT I NEED TO ANALYZE). I have multiple sections like this that I will be looping through and comparing those sections.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eq()`

```js
var text = $('.content > .markdown > p').eq(1).text();
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h4>Available since...</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>Version 1</p>
  </div>
  <h4>Accessible by...</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>SOME TEXT I NEED TO ANALYZE</p>
  </div>
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or for multiple `.content` divs to find second `p` in each one, you can use `each()` and check index

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.markdown > p').each(function(i) {
    if (i == 1) console.log($(this).text());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h4>Available since...</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>Version 1</p>
  </div>
  <h4>Accessible by...</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>SOME TEXT I NEED TO ANALYZE</p>
  </div>
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="content">
  <h4>Available since...</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>Version 1</p>
  </div>
  <h4>Accessible by...</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>SOME Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <div class="markdown">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```